# Element type Invalid React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I just created a project and I m getting this error. No dependencies installed yet

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Container,
  Header,
  Title,
  Button,
  Left,
  Right,
  Body,
  Icon,
} from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Header>
        <Body>
          <Title></Title>
        </Body>
      </Header>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

This error is located at:
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by App)
in App (created by ExpoRoot)
in ExpoRoot
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer

Comment: do you mean dependencies like react-native etc are not installed ?

Comment: those were globally installed. I just created an expo project and wrote this. And the error came up

Answer (score 0):

Did you create project using **expo** or **react-native-cli** and have you changed anything after creating the project?

If this is the **expo cli** you can try closing the metrol bundler and running
`npm install` in your terminal then starting it again.

If this is **react-native-cli** you can try running.

```
npm install
cd ios && pod install
cd ..
```

Answer (score 0):

try running this commands

```
 cd android
./gradlew clean
npm install
```